# Alternative lifestyle for a vampire: How would they run a village/town?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, fantasy-races

**Here's my question:** How would one or multiple vampires use human villages/towns as cattle? How many humans are required to sustain a single vampire and how much space do the humans require? How can this be made more efficient?

**I do not accept answers such as it's fictional or magic** as this is a reality-check. No animal blood either, vampires are picky eaters. The era is set around the 18th century.

I have been playing around with this idea as an alternative for the "vegan vampire" trope, which really isn't that engaging in world building. This idea serves the purpose of integrating vampires with human civilization and how they would survive in a more sustainable way. This is no doubt a safer way to live as opposed to their more feral brethren. Vampires do consider themselves to be nobility after all, so I at least assume they would be more than competent to rule over people and let them benefit from their powers (no magic included this is grounded in reality).

**The idea is that a small dose of the vampire virus could turn people docile making them perfect cattle for the vampire, instead of making more vampires.** This half transformation would allow the pure-blooded vampires to control them like they would with bats. Some humans can be transformed to serve as underlings if they feel the need.

**Vampire biology:** A pure-blooded vampire is more bat-like with winged arms and slender bodies built for flight. They have razor sharp fangs, saliva that prevents coagulation and a stomach specialized to consume liquid food (blood for sustenance and other liquids for leisure). Because of their nocturnal lifestyles they have keen night vision and echolocation, however their skin is pale and vulnerable to sunlight. They are also allergic to garlic and silver. Vampires reproduce sexually to produce pure-blooded offspring but are also carriers of the vampire virus which can transform humans into human-based vampires.

Human-based vampires on the other hand are humans infected by the vampire virus. As such they do not possess wings but do develop fangs and night vision as well as the previously mentioned weaknesses of the vampires. Because they are not built for flight they are physically stronger than pure-bloods however are less intelligent due to the transformation doing a number on their brain. Further exposure to the V-virus causes them to mutate.

Humans who receive small doses of the virus do not change except for their behavior. They become docile and incapable of revolt. They are treated as servants and a food sources. They are fed on in shifts to allow them to recover their blood.

So. I hope this is everything you need. If I have left something out please comment and editing shall ensue.

Comment: You might not accept it, but asking a reality check on a fictional creature like a vampire is meaningless. Whatever you want can hold true.

Comment: "I do not accept answers such as it's fictional or magic as this is a reality-check." Indeed. I do not accept it. The point of making this a reality-check is to get rid of the "Whatever you want can hold true". However if you think the reality-check is not appropriate for this question you can point me towards an alternative.

Comment: You may want to look into the legends that started vampirism since I believe it was originally an allegory  for the rich feeding off the poor in the sense that their luxury was sustained by the suffering of peasants. There are no "good vampires" because being a vampire is an expression of the evil within humans who care only about what others can do for them.

Comment: There is an implied question here "how much blood a vampire needs to sustain him/herself" (which imho should be asked separately).

Comment: @Muuski the legends are *fascinating* because different locations have a different real-world basis for vampires. In some places it's just more or less generic "evil things at night" not unlike the boogeyman. Other places have vampires emerge as a cultural fear of the dead. And other places still do represent the rich "drinking the lifeblood of the poor" in a more literal sense in the legends. A really interesting twist is the Chupacabra and similar creatures that are sort of "local vampires" for some smaller Latin American countries that attack livestock. Since the locals earn their living

Comment: with the animals, a goat or cow drained out of blood may be even scarier than a single person, since without the animal a whole family might starve to death. So, these vampires there personify the fear of somebody taking the trade and livelyhood of the people away from them. In some cases the fears are very pointed towards the USA - some do believe the Chupacabra (and similar) is some failed USA experiment that got loose. Also fun fact - Chupacabra was first mentioned in 1995 - a lot more recent than you might think. And the initial depiction is different than what it "settled on" later.

Comment: "Reality check" simply means that you're asking us to determine if your scenario or parts within it are consistent or reasonable within the given context; so there is no problem at all with you using that tag. Also, kindly consider an attitude adjustment. You're new here and have only asked two questions. You're getting flak I think more because you're behaving like an old cuss than for anything inherent to your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The vampire leaders would be very interested in public health and sustainable farming.**

Yes vampires are spooky and sexy.  Spexy, as it were.  But when they are in charge, they need to figure out ways to maximize the health and number of their herd of humans.  That means public health with preventative care of pregnant women.  Public hygiene so babies do not get diarrhea from dirty water and contagious diseases are kept to a minimum.  Control of transmissible disease.  It also means centrally planned agriculture with erosion control, soil remediation and irrigation with crops chosen for caloric value, and high protein vegetarian diets (to maximize human carrying capacity of the land).  The goal: large healthy farm families.

It means no stupid wars.  People killing people is a waste.  Incursions by warlike neighbors or bandits will be summarily dealt with by the vampires themselves, with foreigners enslaved and eaten.

The vampires can still be spexy after hours.  During working hours they are all business, concerning themselves with important matters that are neither spooky nor sexy.  And their country would be a good one to live in!

Answer (score 2):

I’d look for history books on plantation slavery as that’s what you’re talking about. Blood will be less important than the economics: like other Ruling classes they need an economic basis to support their lifestyle.

Comment: I'm sorry. But your answer is not an answer. I'd propose adding actual information instead of pointing towards research as stackExchange does not like superfluous conversation.

Comment: I was more pointing out a misconception in the premise

Comment: That's always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The show Being Human (and I'm sure many other Vampire dramas) featured something akin to this briefly. Vampires in the modern world - who were far less capable of getting away with murder than their predecessors - have set up essentially "blood spas" in which humans who are paid or coerced exchange their blood.

The idea of how many humans to sustain a single vampire is dependent on what you think vampires are. If you think they are scaled up Vampire Bats, then they would need to consume several dozen liters of blood daily. This would necessitate a rather large settlement with streamlined blood-donation else the vampire would end up killing many people or require modern blood-banking techniques.

If you think of them as humans with an additional requirement for blood instead of water, than 2 liters would be okay. Swapping through 4 humans should be enough without risk of exsanginuation. Though more is always better.

Comment: I believe I said no magic. I also said that the virus makes people incapable of revolt so really there is no need for cooperation. However thank you for asking a question about their diet, I will edit it.

Comment: The virus is functionally equivalent to magic in this situation. But I'll edit my answer

Comment: "The virus is functionally equivalent to magic in this situation" Excuse me, what? Yes vampires don't exist but what exactly do you classify as magic and science-fiction? Magic is usually unexplained. This is more science-fiction than magic as it is a virus after all. Viruses inject RNA and DNA into cells. I'd be like a bite giving rabies except with a vampire.

Comment: I mean a spell of "calm target" would achieve the same effect - even if its unexplained. The virus having a hard science backing doesn't change how your society functions, unless you have doctors going around with vaccines

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR "*Magic is usually unexplained.*" a lot of times magic is quite rigorously explained, though.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR - Your virus has the magical ability to make people incapable of revolt -- i.e., incapable of rational thought, weighing evidence, acting on emotion, self-determinative action, etc. In other words, **magic**. What knowads is saying is that you say you don't want magic in your scenario, but then you turn right around and insert magic into your scenario. In other words, your scenario fails the reality check because it's inconsistent within itself.